# pointer to two-dimension array

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef char trgm[3];

char test[2][3] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

int main(void)
{
    trgm *t;
    t = test;
    printf("%c\n",*(char *)t);
    printf("%c\n",*(char *)*t);
    printf("%c\n",**t);
    return 0;
}
```

the output of three printf is same. I don't understand why the t and *t are same? what does complier do internal?

Comment: Use pen and paper to write down variables, arrays & their values and the pointers. There are just too many pointers to be followed for me to explain it and I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three paths of interpretation of  the same value - the starting address of the memory extent occupied by the array. So dereferencing the value casted to `char *` you will get the value of the first element of the type `char` of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an array variable as containing the memory address of its first element. In your case since the array is a 2D array, the "first element" t[0] is in-fact pointer to the 'first row'. Note that in terms of memory there is no special storage for element t[0] and t[1], it gets converted to appropriate memory offset, but it helps to think that way.   Hence when you deference the pointer (*t), you get the same value as you would get for the array variable.

```
t = [0]  --> 'a','b','c'
    [1]  --> 'd','e','f'
```

Try this `printf("%p %p %p\n", t,*t, t[0]);`, you will get same value for all.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the `typedef char trgm[3];`, then `trgm` refers to *an array of char [3]`. This is important.

When you declare `trgm *t = test`, the pointer `t` is a *pointer to array of char [3]*. By setting `t = test;` you make `t` a pointer that points to the first *row* of `test` (essentially equivalent to `test[0]`. Since an array variable holds (or points to) the first element of `test`, both `t` and `test` point to the same value. Dereferncing the either the pointer `t` or `test` (e.g. `*t` or `*test`) will access the first element of `test`.

Now since `t` is a pointer to array of char [3], it is a pointer with two-levels of indirection and can therefore be dereferenced twice (as can test). Take `test[row][col]`. Let's look at the pointer equivalent for the array. `test can be written as`

```
*(*(test + col) + row)
```

(both `col` and `row` are `0` when referencing the first element (e.g. `test[0][0]`) so the above is simply

```
*(*(test + 0) + 0)
```

**note:** anything plus `0` is just that thing again, so it simplifies to:

```
**test
```

For `t` it is just:

```
(*t)[col]    /* to index cols 0 - 2 */
```

It too can be rewritten as:

```
*((*t) + col)
```

With `col` being zero for the first element, you get

```
**t
```

However, `t` by pointing to the first row, allows pointer arithmetic (e.g. `t = t + 1;`, or just `t++`) to update `t` to point to the second row, and so on.

So, in sum, whether you are looking at `test` or you are looking at `t`, both initially reference the address for the first element in `test`, both are (or can be considered) pointers with two levels of indirection, and dereferencing each once, or twice, will still point at the original element in test. You can use `t` to access all values in your array, for instance:

```
for (; t < &test[2]; t++)
    printf (" %c, %c, %c\n", (*t)[0], (*t)[1], (*t)[2]);
putchar ('\n');
```

Which will output:

```
 a, b, c
 d, e, f
```

Lastly, there is no need to make `test` a global variable. Avoid global variables to reduce the chance of name collision. Declare `test` in `main()` and pass it pointer to it to any other function it is required.

Putting that altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char trgm[3];

int main(void)
{
    char test[][3] = {{'a','b','c'},
                      {'d','e','f'}};
    trgm *t;
    t = test;
    printf("%c\n",*(char *)t);
    printf("%c\n",*(char *)*t);
    printf("%c\n",**t);

    for (; t < &test[2]; t++)
        printf (" %c, %c, %c\n", (*t)[0], (*t)[1], (*t)[2]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/p2x3
a
a
a
a, b, c
d, e, f
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: struct list{
  int item;
  struct list *next;
  };

Comment: struct list **lpp;
 for(lpp = &list; *lpp != NULL; lpp = &(*lpp)->next)
  {
  if((*lpp)->item == i)
   {
   *lpp = (*lpp)->next;
   break;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: in above example, lpp and *lpp are different address, I am confused and look forward to your advice.

Comment: Sorry for the dely, I've been working on my real job... Of course `t` and `*t` have different address. Recall a *pointer* is nothing but a variable that holds ***the address to something else*** as its value. So `t` is a pointer with its own address, and the value stored at `t` is the address for something else (i.e. a separate address) which you obtain by dereferencing `t` (e.g. `*t`). Take look at [What are pointers?](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-pointers-fundamentals) and the link at the bottom (Advanced Pointers).